# Create dataset from array of numbers with d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a simple array with sums for each category of thing. A simplified version:

```
var quantities = [{"type": "apple","number": 51}, 
{"type": "orange","number": 19}, 
{"type": "lemon","number": 11}];
```

From this data I'm going to draw one circle for each thing, ie 51 circles with type=apple, 19 for orange, 11 for lemon. I'd like to create an array based on this data with one entry for each object -

```
dataset = [{apple},{apple},{apple}...]
```

What would be the best way to create this dataset in d3? I've been trying the data map functions with no luck. Or is there a better way to draw the correct number of each category based on my original array, without the dataset step?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some maps and reduces to convert this in one line:

```
var quantities = [{"type": "apple","number": 51}, 
{"type": "orange","number": 19}, 
{"type": "lemon","number": 11}];

var joined = quantities.map(function(x) {
  return Array.apply(null, new Array(x.number)).map(function (y) {
    return x.type; }); }).reduce(function(prev, z) {
      return prev.concat(z); }, []) 

console.log(joined);
```

In case you were wondering what is `Array.apply(null, new Array(x.number))`… this is an idiom to create an initialized array from an uninitialized array of specified length, for the reason that the former is *mappable* and the latter is not.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: I am glad. We have a little tradition here, that when an answer suits your need you accept it by ticking this grey-bordered mark under voting triangle.